# GridView Control (Visual Studio ASP.Net 2008 C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I'm having a GridView of about 7000 rows and i want to add an update button on each row. When the user click that button,i want to display all the information in that particular row into the textboxes and let the user update and save.

The names of my textboxes are:

> txtEmployeeNumber, txtSurname, txtFirstName, txtPosition

My GridView name is: gvMain
My server name is: bisweb\bisweb
My database name is: x_kgabo
Can anyone help!

Comment: For what platform Web, Desktop (WinForms, WPF), Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add template field in your gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnRateIt" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CommandName="RateIt"
                        runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/RateIt.gif" />

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button Runat="server" ID="makeSomehtingButton"
CommandName="makeSomething" 
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>'>
</asp:Button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```